# Matching records to nested routes in show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, nested-resources

How can you limit the records that are available to the show action? The problem I'm having is that you can manually change the ID in the URL  and look at projects that do not belong to the company.

My Routes Look like this:

/companies/:id/projects/:id

This is the show action

projects_controller.rb

```
def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @project }
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :companies do
    resources :projects
    resources :employees
    resources :requests do
      put 'accept', :on => :member
    end
end
```

project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title

  belongs_to :company

 validates :title, presence: true
end
```

company.rb

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name

```
has_many :projects
```

end

Comment: Does companies and project have associations?

Comment: Yeah it does, I've added some model code to show the setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a `has_many` relationship between `Company` and `Project` I would change your controller code to this:

```
def show
  @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
  @project = @company.projects.find(params[:id])
end
```

Keep in mind though that this does not really solve your problem as people can still change the `company_id` and view other companies easily. What you need is a more solid authorization framework like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities) that prevents unauthorized access to resources.

Comment: So I can leave it open as is and impliment the access through authorisation?

Comment: I would still do both to prevent users who have access to multiple companies to see project from company b inside company a's layout (in case they mess with the params) not really necessary but also not hard to do ;)

Answer (score 0):

May be, you should use smth like this:

> @project = @company.projects.find(params[:id])

Check [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the action to this

```
def show
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    @project = @company.projects.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @project }
    end
end
```